# Bluemix Blockchain

Tags: ibm-cloud, blockchain

Facing below error for quite a long time today. Is this frequent?
We are trying to run a sample app locally [connecting to bluemix blockchain]
Also tried to install/deploy directly into blockchain.
Both results in same error on login page itself. Also gets ERR 500/

Waiting on the node server to open up so we can talk to the blockchain. This app is likely still starting up. Check the server logs if this message does not go away in 1 minute.
This application cannot run without the blockchain network :(

Answer (score 1):

The "starter network" blockchain has been experiencing intermittent capacity overflow issues. We currently have availability; have you tried this recently?  Try again andlet us know if you get the same error. If yes, please open a support service ticket via Bluemix dashboard. 
Hope this helps, and thanks for using blockchain!